# Combining a line chart and a Bar plot in Python pptx

Tags: python-pptx

Hi @Scanny

I am basically trying to combine a line chart and a bar chart accessing its XML.

I tried to extract the XML through opc.

I want the organic change series to be a Line chart and the and the Volume change series to be a bar chart in the same chart.

Is there any in built function for this, or do i have to write my own?

```
<c:chart>\n    
<c:plotArea>\n      
<c:barChart>\n        
<c:barDir val="col"/>\n        
<c:grouping val="stacked"/>\n        
<c:ser>\n          
<c:idx val="0"/>\n          
<c:order val="0"/>\n          
<c:tx>\n            
<c:strRef>\n              
<c:f>Sheet1!$B$1</c:f>\n              
<c:strCache>\n                
<c:ptCount val="1"/>\n                
<c:pt idx="0">\n                  
<c:v>Organic Change</c:v>\n   
</c:pt>\n              
</c:strCache>\n            
</c:strRef>\n          
</c:tx>\n          
<c:invertIfNegative val="0"/>\n          
<c:dPt>\n            
<c:idx val="0"/>\n            
<c:marker>\n              
<c:spPr>\n                
<a:solidFill>\n                  
<a:srgbClr val="D0E4A6"/>\n                
</a:solidFill>\n             
 </c:spPr>\n            
</c:marker>\n            
<c:spPr>\n              
<a:solidFill>\n                
<a:srgbClr val="D0E4A6"/>\n              
</a:solidFill>\n            
</c:spPr>\n          
</c:dPt>\n          
<c:cat>\n            
<c:strRef>\n              
<c:f>Sheet1!$A$2:$A$2</c:f>\n              
<c:strCache>\n                
<c:ptCount val="1"/>\n                
<c:pt idx="0">\n                  
<c:v>Toothpaste</c:v>\n                
</c:pt>\n              
</c:strCache>\n            
</c:strRef>\n          
</c:cat>\n          
<c:val>\n            
<c:numRef>\n             
 <c:f>Sheet1!$B$2:$B$2</c:f>\n              
<c:numCache>\n                
<c:formatCode>General</c:formatCode>\n                
<c:ptCount val="1"/>\n                
<c:pt idx="0">\n                  
<c:v>2.4</c:v>\n                
</c:pt>\n              
</c:numCache>\n            
</c:numRef>\n          
</c:val>\n        
</c:ser>\n        
<c:ser>\n          
<c:idx val="1"/>\n          
<c:order val="1"/>\n          
<c:tx>\n            
<c:strRef>\n              
<c:f>Sheet1!$C$1</c:f>\n              
<c:strCache>\n                
<c:ptCount val="1"/>\n                
<c:pt idx="0">\n                  
<c:v>Volume Change</c:v>\n                
</c:pt>\n              
</c:strCache>\n            
</c:strRef>\n          
</c:tx>\n          
<c:invertIfNegative val="0"/>\n          
<c:dPt>\n            
<c:idx val="0"/>\n            
<c:marker>\n              
<c:spPr>\n                
<a:solidFill>\n                  
<a:srgbClr val="94CEFF"/>\n                
</a:solidFill>\n              
</c:spPr>\n            
</c:marker>\n            
<c:spPr>\n              
<a:solidFill>\n                
<a:srgbClr val="94CEFF"/>\n              
</a:solidFill>\n            
</c:spPr>\n          
</c:dPt>\n          
<c:cat>\n            
<c:strRef>\n              
<c:f>Sheet1!$A$2:$A$2</c:f>\n              
<c:strCache>\n                
<c:ptCount val="1"/>\n                
<c:pt idx="0">\n                  
<c:v>Toothpaste</c:v>\n                
</c:pt>\n              
</c:strCache>\n            
</c:strRef>\n          
</c:cat>\n          
<c:val>\n            
<c:numRef>\n              
<c:f>Sheet1!$C$2:$C$2</c:f>\n              
<c:numCache>\n                
<c:formatCode>General</c:formatCode>\n                
<c:ptCount val="1"/>\n                
<c:pt idx="0">\n                  
<c:v>0.5</c:v>\n                
</c:pt>\n              
</c:numCache>\n            
</c:numRef>\n          
</c:val>\n        
</c:ser>\n        
<c:gapWidth val="15"/>\n        
<c:overlap val="100"/>\n        
<c:axId val="-2068027336"/>\n        
<c:axId val="-2113994440"/>\n      
</c:barChart>\n      
<c:catAx>\n        
<c:axId val="-2068027336"/>\n        
<c:scaling>\n          
<c:orientation val="minMax"/>\n        
</c:scaling>\n        
<c:delete val="0"/>\n        
<c:axPos val="b"/>\n        
<c:majorTickMark val="none"/>\n        
<c:minorTickMark val="none"/>\n        
<c:tickLblPos val="none"/>\n        
<c:txPr>\n          
<a:bodyPr/>\n          
<a:lstStyle/>\n          
<a:p>\n            
<a:pPr>\n              
<a:defRPr sz="1000" b="1"/>\n            
</a:pPr>\n          
</a:p>\n        
</c:txPr>\n        
<c:crossAx val="-2113994440"/>\n        
<c:crosses val="autoZero"/>\n        
<c:auto val="1"/>\n        
<c:lblAlgn val="ctr"/>\n        
<c:lblOffset val="100"/>\n        
<c:noMultiLvlLbl val="0"/>\n      
</c:catAx>\n      
<c:valAx>\n        
<c:axId val="-2113994440"/>\n        
<c:scaling/>\n        
<c:delete val="0"/>\n        
<c:axPos val="l"/>\n        
<c:majorTickMark val="none"/>\n        
<c:minorTickMark val="none"/>\n        
<c:tickLblPos val="nextTo"/>\n        
<c:txPr>\n          
<a:bodyPr/>\n          
<a:lstStyle/>\n          
<a:p>\n            
<a:pPr>\n              
<a:defRPr sz="1000"/>\n            
</a:pPr>\n          
</a:p>\n        
</c:txPr>\n        
<c:crossAx val="-2068027336"/>\n        
<c:crosses val="autoZero"/>\n      
</c:valAx>\n    
</c:plotArea>\n    
<c:legend>\n      
<c:legendPos val="b"/>\n      
<c:txPr>\n        
<a:bodyPr/>\n        
<a:lstStyle/>\n        
<a:p>\n          
<a:pPr>\n            
<a:defRPr sz="1200"/>\n          
</a:pPr>\n        
</a:p>\n      
</c:txPr>\n    
</c:legend>\n    
<c:dispBlanksAs val="gap"/>\n  
</c:chart>\n  
<c:txPr>\n    
<a:bodyPr/>\n    
<a:lstStyle/>\n    
<a:p>\n      
<a:pPr>\n        
<a:defRPr sz="1800"/>\n      
</a:pPr>\n      
<a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>\n    
</a:p>\n  
</c:txPr>\n  
<c:externalData r:id="rId1">\n    
<c:autoUpdate val="0"/>\n  
</c:externalData>\n
</c:chartSpace>\n'
```

Comment: It's possible to do (anything you can do in PowerPoint can be represented in the XML), but I'm afraid you'll have to work out the XML manipulation details yourself. There's no API for this yet. Best bet is to start with a .pptx with such a chart made by hand in PowerPoint and use its XML as a model.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. If you're using a template with a dummy multi-plot chart, then you can do the following (if the dimensions stay the same):

```
prs = Presentation('Presentation1.pptx')
slide = prs.slides[0]

for el in slide.shapes[1].chart.plots[0].series[0]._element.xpath("c:val/c:numRef/c:numCache/c:pt/c:v"):
    print(el.text)
    el.text = "0.3"

prs.save('xmlDummy.pptx')
```

plot 0 is in my case the bar and 1 the line-chart.